# How to count number of links returned by xpath expression

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to count the number of instances an xpath identifies as true. I have built a scrapy code which lists out the number of times the xpath returns true when the condition is met, but i would like to return the number of times it returns a true result.

my code is below - i'm a newbie so any help is super appreciated!!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['examplewebsite.com']
    start_urls = ['https://examplewebsite.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        example1 = bool(response.xpath('//*').re('example1'))
        example2 = bool(response.xpath('//*').re('example2'))

        yield{'example1' : example1,
                'example2' : example2}
```

Comment: Do you need a number of results for the `.re()` or `.xpath()`?

Comment: Hi, I am looking to count the responses of example1. I am looking to identify all instances of the a word in the html. Does that make sense? Apologies - total newbie here. many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `len()`:

```
example1_counter = len(response.xpath('//YOUR_XPATH_HERE').re('example1'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I tried len to begin with, but it returns a load of numbers on multiple rows in excel when i run the spider. I'm trying to get the total count of matches against the word in the html returned in one row of an excel file. Is there a way to do this? thanks!